# Deriving a crypto key from a password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to generate a key using the .net 2.0 PasswordDeriveBytes class.

```
  PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("blahblahblah",null);
  byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  byte[] key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 128, iv);
```

The code throws "CryptographicException: Invalid flags specified." when trying to execute the CryptDeriveKey method above. I'm trying to encrypt a database entry in asp.net and this is my first shot a crypto. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN:

*"If the keySize parameter is set to 0 bits, the default key size for the specified algorithm is used."*

[MSDN PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.cryptderivekey.aspx)

```
PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("blahblahblah",null);
byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
byte[] key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 0, iv);
```

Unless you have a good reason for specifying the size I'd suggest just leaving it 0.

Answer (score 2):

TripleDES has a key length of 192 bits try:

```
byte[] key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, iv);
```

Try [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) for example code

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) instead of PasswordDeriveBytes.